# Renaming attribute entry

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-1, product-attribute

I have an attribute called "Size" (Attribute Code = config_size, attribute_id = 146)

I need to re-name some of the entries but when I try and do it from Admin it doesn't change.

Where can I change the entry in the database?

Answer (score 0):

**query:**

```
select value.* from eav_attribute_option_value as value
inner join eav_attribute_option as options on options.option_id=value.option_id
inner join eav_attribute as attribute on attribute.attribute_id=options.attribute_id
where attribute_code='config_size';
```

--> this will give all the records from the database and you might want to change the value from there indeed if your backend is broken. good luck